# Is it possible to post images with Gwibber?

Tags: gwibber

If I drag and drop an image to gwibber, will sending work? (Will it upload the image and link to it). Or is this not supported?

*P.S. - I've never tried, but I just thought of it.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latest version Gwibber 3.1.0 can upload images to imageshack, shorten the url and put the link into the messagebox. You'll find a "+" icon next to the send button to upload the image. In order to install this version in Ubuntu Natty and prior, you've got to use the [Gwibber-Daily-PPA](https://launchpad.net/~gwibber-daily/+archive/ppa).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwibber-daily/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Ubuntu Oneiric 11.10 will ship with a version of Gwibber which is new enough for this feature, so that you won't have to deal with the PPA anymore.

Comment: I cannot find any such feature for images, nor any "+" button...

Answer (score 3):

Would be a nice feature but Gwibber doesn't support this.